# import data from Excel file through phpspreadsheet and check existence of records in the database symfony 4

Tags: symfony, import, doctrine, sonata, phpspreadsheet

I would to import data from Excel file through phpspreadsheet and read row by row and test if the record exist in the database as follows

```
$reader = new XlsxReader();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($tmp_name);
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
$highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
fwrite($fp, "File: " . $_FILES['catalogue']['name'] . "\n");
fwrite($fp, "Number of Row : " . $highestRow . "\n");
fwrite($fp, "Highest Column : " . $highestColumn . "\n");
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Catalogue::class);
$list = [];

$it = $worksheet->getRowIterator(1);
foreach ($it as $row) {
    $cellIt = $row->getCellIterator();
    $r = [];
    foreach ($cellIt as $cell) {
        $r[] = $cell->getFormattedValue();
    }
    $list[] = $r;
}
foreach ($list as $x) {
    $v = $x[0];
    fwrite($fp, $v . "\n");
    $s = $em->findOneBy(['Species' => $x[0]]);
    if ($s) {
        if ($s->getSpecies() ==$x[0]){
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', $v . 'Already Existing' . '<br>');
        fwrite($fp, $x[0].'Already Exist in the catalogue'. "\n");
        }
        if ($s->getSpecies() !=$x[0]) {
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('sucess', $x[0] . 'To be added' . '<br>');
       fwrite($fp, $x[0]. 'to be added to the catalogue'. "\n");
        }

    }

    //
}
fclose($fp);
$request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'File is valid, and was successfully processed.!' . '<br>' . "<a href=" . $url . ">Log Link</a>");
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('Catalogue_list'));
```

Checking if the record exists in the database works only for the half of the records as follows:

```
 - Asparagopsis armata        
 - Abudefduf sexfasciatus
 - Abudefduf sexfasciatus Already Exist in the catalogue    
 - Abudefduf vaigiensis
 - Abudefduf vaigiensis Already Exist in the catalogue
 - Caretta caretta
 - Chelonya mydas
```

Only the three first records are in the database. What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The call to the `findOneBy` method will only return something if the species already exists on the database, you don't need the nested `if`s. You should just move the second one (the one with the `!=` condition) to an `else` block, since now it can never be reached:

```
$s = $em->findOneBy(['Species' => $x[0]]);
if ($s) {  // $s is set, so the species exists
    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', $v . 'Already Existing' . '<br>');
    fwrite($fp, $x[0].'Already Exist in the catalogue'. "\n");
} else {  // Not found
    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('sucess', $x[0] . 'To be added' . '<br>');
   fwrite($fp, $x[0]. 'to be added to the catalogue'. "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = $em->findOneBy(['Species' => $x[0]]);
if ($s) {  // $s is set, so the species exists
    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', $v . 'Already Existing' . '<br>');
    fwrite($fp, $x[0].'Already Exist in the catalogue'. "\n");
} else {  // Not found
    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('sucess', $x[0] . 'To be added' . '<br>');
   fwrite($fp, $x[0]. 'to be added to the catalogue'. "\n");
    $catalogue = new Catalogue();
    $catalogue->setSpecies($x[0]);
    $em->persist($s);
    $em->flush();
}
```

```
I got this error Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Catalogue::setSpecies() must be of the type string, null given, Any help
```

Comment: To add further information [edit] your question or comment on answers rather than create an answer if it's not a solution to the problem. That said, is any record inserted at all? If they are, you are probably reading past the last row with data or there are empty cells. Try using `getHighestDataRow()` instead of `getHighestRow()`. You can also `print_r($list)` to check that it contains what you expect.